# How can i get the last inserted value of primary kay field?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I am using MySQL.I have to get the last inserted record's primary key value.
How can i get this?

Comment: Define "last inserted". "Last inserted *by anybody*"? "The auto-increment key that got generated for the row *you just inserted*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will return the last inserted id.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

OR

```
if ((result = mysql_store_result(&mysql)) == 0 &&
    mysql_field_count(&mysql) == 0 &&
    mysql_insert_id(&mysql) != 0)
{
    used_id = mysql_insert_id(&mysql);
}
```

Comment: its the $link_identifier, don't know why theres a & insted of the $

Answer (score 4):

```
mysqli_insert_id()
PDO::lastInsertId()
mysql_insert_id()
```

It's well worth checking the documentation if you are likely to meet "race" conditions. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are two function that return this value:

`mysql_insert_id()`--> PHP function

`LAST_INSERT_ID()`--> MySQL function that can be used by PHP and other Languages or in MySQL command line interface or MySQL front-end

Answer (score 0):

Use follwoing query:

```
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```